# How can I dynamically update my AWS CloudWatch dashboards?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have several dashboards in CloudWatch that represent a view of my infrastructure : Number of instances from an autoscaling-group that are currently running, the CPU/Disk usage per instance etc. 
However, when I update an autoscaling-group, I have to manually update the dashboards (autoscaling-group ID) to include its EC2 instances in the display.
I'm looking for some kind of metric/dimension that can filter autoscaling-groups by tag. Is it possible, if yes then how? if no, how can I make it differently? 
Thanks.